# Empty rows on right hand side of LEFT JOIN show constant string

Tags: sql, ms-access

TL;DR: This seems to actually be a bug in the Access database engine, see
[Bug: Outer join expressions retrieved wrongly](http://allenbrowne.com/BugOuterJoinExpression.html)

### Tables

`tPerson` stores persons...

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Person_ID | Person_Name |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 | John        |
|         2 | Jack        |
|         3 | Jill        |
|         4 | Jane        |
+-----------+-------------+
```

... and `tDate` stores assignments of date ranges to persons (1:n).

```
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| Date_ID | f_Person_ID |  DateFrom  |   DateTo   |
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|       1 |           1 | 05.08.2016 | 05.08.2016 |
|       2 |           1 | 07.08.2016 | 10.08.2016 |
|       3 |           3 | 26.08.2016 | 29.08.2016 |
|       4 |           2 | 01.09.2016 | 05.09.2016 |
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

### Queries

I want to see all persons, with their assigned date ranges (where existing), in a specified period. For display in a combobox, the date range is concatenated into one column.

I have this input query `qDateString`:

```sql
SELECT f_Person_ID, [DateFrom] & "  to  " & [DateTo] AS DateRange
FROM tDate
WHERE DateFrom Between #8/1/2016# And #8/31/2016#;
```

giving me

```
+-------------+----------------------------+
| f_Person_ID |         DateRange          |
+-------------+----------------------------+
|           1 | 05.08.2016  to  05.08.2016 |
|           1 | 07.08.2016  to  10.08.2016 |
|           3 | 26.08.2016  to  29.08.2016 |
+-------------+----------------------------+
```

To show all persons, I use a LEFT JOIN. If a person has multiple date ranges assigned, I get multiple rows, this is wanted.

```sql
SELECT tPerson.Person_ID, tPerson.Person_Name, qDateString.DateRange
FROM tPerson 
  LEFT JOIN qDateString ON tPerson.Person_ID = qDateString.f_Person_ID;
```

For persons without date ranges, I expect the "right-hand" columns of the LEFT JOIN to be Null. But what I get is:

```
+-----------+-------------+----------------------------+
| Person_ID | Person_Name |         DateRange          |
+-----------+-------------+----------------------------+
|         1 | John        | 07.08.2016  to  10.08.2016 |
|         1 | John        | 05.08.2016  to  05.08.2016 |
|         2 | Jack        |   to                       |
|         3 | Jill        | 26.08.2016  to  29.08.2016 |
|         4 | Jane        |   to                       |
+-----------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

WTF. What are these `"  to  "` strings doing in there?

### Questions

1 - Why does Access do this? I assume that the two queries are not executed sequentially, but a combined execution plan is formed. But still, shouldn't `qDateString` columns always be empty if there is no row on their side of the LEFT JOIN?

2 - As a workaround, I use `IsNull()` in the input query:

```sql
SELECT f_Person_ID, 
  IIf(IsNull([DateFrom]), Null, [DateFrom] & "  to  " & [DateTo]) AS ModDateRange
```

which gives me the desired result. Is there a less clunky way?

---

**Edit**

---

To see that this behavior is not quite normal, do this in SQL Server. To make it easier, I changed dates to integers.

```sql
-- Base tables and data
CREATE TABLE [tPerson] (
    [Person_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Person_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tPerson] PRIMARY KEY ([Person_ID])
) 
GO

INSERT [tPerson] ([Person_ID], [Person_Name]) VALUES (1, N'John')
INSERT [tPerson] ([Person_ID], [Person_Name]) VALUES (2, N'Jack')
INSERT [tPerson] ([Person_ID], [Person_Name]) VALUES (3, N'Jill')
INSERT [tPerson] ([Person_ID], [Person_Name]) VALUES (4, N'Jane')
GO

CREATE TABLE [tDate] (
    [Date_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [f_Person_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [iFrom] [int] NOT NULL,
    [iTo] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tDate] PRIMARY KEY ([Date_ID])
)
GO

INSERT [tDate] ([Date_ID], [f_Person_ID], [iFrom], [iTo]) VALUES (1, 1, 2, 3)
INSERT [tDate] ([Date_ID], [f_Person_ID], [iFrom], [iTo]) VALUES (2, 1, 10, 20)
INSERT [tDate] ([Date_ID], [f_Person_ID], [iFrom], [iTo]) VALUES (3, 3, 1, 1)
INSERT [tDate] ([Date_ID], [f_Person_ID], [iFrom], [iTo]) VALUES (4, 2, 99, 100)
GO

-- Input query (view)
CREATE VIEW qDateString
AS
SELECT 
    f_Person_ID,
    CONVERT(varchar, iFrom) + ' to ' + CONVERT(varchar, iTo) AS DateRange
FROM tDate
WHERE iFrom BETWEEN 1 AND 10
GO

-- Actual query with LEFT JOIN
SELECT tPerson.Person_ID, tPerson.Person_Name, qDateString.DateRange
FROM tPerson 
  LEFT JOIN qDateString ON tPerson.Person_ID = qDateString.f_Person_ID;
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| Person_ID | Person_Name | DateRange |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|         1 | John        | 2 to 3    |
|         1 | John        | 10 to 20  |
|         2 | Jack        | NULL      |
|         3 | Jill        | 1 to 1    |
|         4 | Jane        | NULL      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: "  to  " is about your application. fix your code.

Comment: @Doruk: I have no idea what this comment wants to tell me. Please explain.

Comment: You do `[DateFrom] & "  to  " & [DateTo] AS DateRange`. When no hit in the right sida table, only `to` is returned.

Comment: @jarlh: yes, obviously. The question is **why**. If `qDateString` were a table, it would be Null for these rows. My assumption was that it should behave similarly with a query. But maybe I'm simply misinterpreting how a LEFT JOIN should work.

Comment: The `to` literal doesn't belong to a table. It will always be there, no matter if there are any right side values or not.

Comment: Do you get what you want if you change the column expression to this?: `[DateFrom] + "  to  " + [DateTo] AS DateRange`

Comment: @jpw: Thanks, great find (that I somehow missed). I was wary to call this a bug in the database engine, but it seems to actually be one. Feel free to post this as answer (or mark as duplicate).

Comment: @HansUp: This was my first choice for a workaround too, but it doesn't work for dates. It would work with text columns (I think). And before you ask, `CStr([DateFrom]) & "  to  " ...` generated an error too.

Comment: @Andre I closed as duplicate as the other question seems close enough to explain the behaviour (and since you know how to work around it anyway).

Comment: The SQL from `qDateString` works as a subquery: `SELECT p.Person_ID, p.Person_Name, d.DateRange FROM tPerson AS p LEFT JOIN (SELECT f_Person_ID, IIf([DateFrom] + [DateTo] Is Null, Null, [DateFrom] & "  to  " & [DateTo]) AS DateRange FROM tDate WHERE DateFrom Between #8/1/2016# And #8/31/2016#) AS d ON p.Person_ID = d.f_Person_ID;`  I don't know whether that helps, but I was curious to explore.

Comment: @HansUp: Thanks. The actual `qDateString` is a bit more complicated than shown, so I have it as separate query for easier modification and debugging. But I might still consider doing this when all is settled, just to have one query less in the db.