# Why does using a subquery inside a left join give a completely different answer than an equivalent table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using a left join in an Access query to get a table with a column added that only applies to a few rows. When I use a subquery as the table being joined it gives me a final table with the new column having the same value for all the rows. When I build a table that gives the same exact output as the subquery it works how I want it to. Why does a subquery and a table give me different results if they look the same.

I've looked over other questions about the difference between a table and a derived table(what I think I get using the subquery) and there doesn't seem to be a difference between the two.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *, "P" AS PColumn FROM TableX, TableY WHERE TableX.x = TableY.y) AS Table2 
  ON (Table1.x = Table2.x)
WHERE Table1.X > 2
```

Every value in PColumn is "P". When I build a table that looks exactly like the subquery result and use that in place of the subquery, only row 5 has a PColumn value of "P" and the rest are null, which is what I want. The subquery and the table have the exact same values but different outputs in the outer SELECT statement

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how `left join` works.

Comment: This may be the same issue I experienced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830377/empty-rows-on-right-hand-side-of-left-join-show-constant-string), with the constant value showing up in rows where it shouldn't. Not 100% sure though if it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After confirming that my previous suggestions do not resolve [the bug](http://allenbrowne.com/BugOuterJoinExpression.html), instead *leverage the bug* to obtain expected results:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT TableX.x, Iif(TableX.x Is Null, Null, "P") AS PColumn 
     FROM TableX INNER JOIN TableY 
        ON TableX.x = TableY.y) AS Table2 
  ON (Table1.x = Table2.x)
WHERE Table1.X > 2
```

If Allen Brown is correct, the Access query optimizer executes a calculated field (i.e. static value) AFTER the join, so just make the field consider the existence of a normally non-null to reproduce correct outer join (i.e. left join) results.

Comment: Rant: It's sad that this bug was formally documented years ago, yet recent versions have not fixed this.  Bug's that affect data validity should take priority over all the other cosmetic and non-critical crap that is always added with updates.

Answer (score 1):

As inferred by the comments, this looks to be another occurrence of a bug present in the query optimiser of the JET database engine used by MS Access when evaluating outer joins, as described by Allen Browne in his article [here](http://allenbrowne.com/BugOuterJoinExpression.html).

Consider the following [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the bug:

**Table1**

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
```

**Table2**

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

**SQL**

```
select * from table1 left join (select table2.id, "x" as X from table2) q on table1.id = q.id
```

**Should return:**

```
+-----------+------+---+
| table1.id | q.id | X |
+-----------+------+---+
|         1 |    1 | x |
|         2 |      |   |
+-----------+------+---+
```

**Actually returns:**

```
+-----------+------+---+
| table1.id | q.id | X |
+-----------+------+---+
|         1 |    1 | x |
|         2 |      | x |
+-----------+------+---+
```

Comment: Cheers for a great minimal example!