# MS Access LEFT JOIN fills empty cells

Tags: ms-access, left-join

I have two tables in Access:

Table1:

```
  ID
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

Table2:

```
  ID
1 A
2 B
3 D
```

and a query (Query1) that adds a new column to Table 1:

```
SELECT [Table1].ID
,"NEW CATEGORY" AS Category
FROM [Table1]
```

Which looks like this:

```
  ID     Category
1 A      NEW CATEGORY
2 B      NEW CATEGORY
3 C      NEW CATEGORY
```

Now, if I join Query1 to Table2, like this:

```
SELECT [Table2].ID
,[Query1].ID
,[Query1].Category 
FROM [Table2] 
LEFT JOIN [Query1] ON ([Table2].ID = [Query1].ID)
```

I get the following result:

```
  Table2.ID     Query1.ID     Category
1 A             A             NEW CATEGORY
2 B             B             NEW CATEGORY
3 D                           NEW CATEGORY
```

"NEW CATEGORY" magically appears in row #3 in the Category column, whereas I am expecting an empty cell there.

Any ideas of the source of this strange behavior, or how it can be avoided?

Comment: This is a variation of the OUTER JOIN bug described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830377/empty-rows-on-right-hand-side-of-left-join-show-constant-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170426/access-2007-left-join-to-a-query-returns-error-instead-of-null) and by [Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/BugOuterJoinExpression.html).

Comment: In your case the Expression is simply a constant string.